# Slicing rectifiable sets with maps into the sphere

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, lipschitz-functions

**Notation and Context** (Might not be helpful)

Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a countably $\mathcal{H}^{M}$-rectifiable set. If
$f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ is a Lipschitz function, then we can find 
 subset $S_+\subset S$ on which $S$ has a tangent space, 
$\nabla^S f$ exists, and $\nabla^S f \not= 0$.  For this subset the following
statement holds:

> For almost every $t\in\mathbb{R}^k$, $S_t = f^{-1}(t)\cap S_+$ is a countably $\mathcal{H}^{M-k}$-rectifiable set.  Moreover, given an $\mathcal{H}^{M}$ measurable
>   function $g$ on $S$, we have the coarea formula
>
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\left(\int_{S_t} g\,d\mathcal{H}^{M-k}\right)\,d\mathcal{H}^k = \int_S g\,(J_k^Sf) \,d\mathcal{H}^{M}.$$

Here $J_k^S f$ is the $k$-dimensional Jacobian of $f$ on the surface $S$.  For a more detailed discussion, look at section 5.3-5.4, and perhaps section 7.6 of Krantz and Parks' book *Geometric Integration Theory*, available online at http://www.math.wustl.edu/~sk/books/root.pdf.

**Actual Question**

My question is about a special case where $f$ does not satisfy the hypotheses 
above, but is still a fairly nice function.  Let $M=2$ and $n=3$, so that $S$ is a two-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Let 
$f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ be a map into the 1-sphere $\mathbb{S}^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$
f(x,y,z) = \frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.
$$
First off, this is not a Lipschitz function because of its behavior at the origin.  The second problem is that I don't want to think of $f$ as a map into $\mathbb{R}^2$, because then both sides of the coarea formula are zero and that's not useful to me.

What I actually expect to be true is:

> > $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}\left(\int_{f^{-1}(\theta)\cap S} \,d\mathcal{H}^{1}\right)\,d\mathcal{H}^1(\theta) = \int_S |x^2+y^2|^{-1/2} \,d\mathcal{H}^{2}.$$

This is the coarea formula written above with $g=1$, $k=1$ (since $f$ maps into a one-dimensional set $\mathbb{S}^1$), and I used $|x^2+y^2|^{-1/2}$ for 
$J_1^S f$.

In summary, what I want to know is

- Is the formula I stated true?
- What about higher-dimensional analogues where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{S}^{n-2}$?

Comment: Yes this works. The formula for Lipschitz maps extends to locally Lipschitz case by exhaustion, since the integrand is nonnegative in your situation.  The coarea formula for maps between different dimensions is in Evans-Gariepy (Measure theory... section 3.4). I don't have a reference for the manifold case, but it works exactly the same way because a manifold can be covered by $(1+\epsilon)$-biLipschitz coordinate patches.

Comment: Great!  Thanks so much, I should take a look at Evans-Gariepy.